# Reference named ranges in external workbook with formula criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, named-ranges

**Need Help on Named Ranges in Formulas**:

I have a second workbook `('TEST.xlsx')` as the destination, referencing worksheet-scoped named ranges (in 12 columns X 75 rows) in the source workbook `('FLOW.xlsx')`. I want to create a formula that will match a look-up value (a date entered into cell `C3` in `TEST` that will return the matching named range IF there are 2 or more blank cells in that matched named range/column and the remaining named ranges/columns in that set of 12 columns with 2+ blank cells. The 12 separate columns in the source workbook `('FLOW')` are named by month, year and location `(ex., "jan_2019_class.1","feb_2019_class.1", etc.)`, the worksheet columns being `C, H, M, R, W, AB, AG, AL, AQ, AV, BA`, and `BF`. The rows are 80-155. I've only been able to make a simple working `COUNTBLANK` formula in my `TEST` workbook, ex.:

`=COUNTBLANK('[FLOW.xlsx]Class_1-Chart'!jan_2019_class.1)`

But NOT for successive columns (with different named ranges and the columns are non-sequential); and I can't figure out the functioning formula to combine with this to get the count AND data returned by criteria as described above. Please, no VBA/macros.

Thank you in advance for the help!

['TEST.xlsx' Screen Shot-RVSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpJdV.png)

[FLOW.xlsx- sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jcMW.png)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Terry W!

Comment: Terry W:  The desired outcome is:  Enter a desired start date (format: jan_2020_class.1) in cell C3 in TEST that will reference (or match) that class' worksheet in the source workbook FLOW and determine in that same year if: a) there are 2 or more blank cells in any of the 12 non-sequential columns, AND b) 2 or more blanks for 2 or more COLUMNS (months); then return the named range for the first of such columns in TEST's cell C6:C11. 
The goal: Find an opening for a starting student by entering a desired start month & year in TEST and identifying the named range by criteria in FLOW.  Thanks!!

Comment: Terry W: I've also revised the TEST sheet image and added a sample shot of the FLOW sheet (Class 1 only) in original post above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches but I personally prefer the use of helper rows/columns/cells and named ranges.

In my demonstration I used two class attendant schedule in two different year from January to June as shown below (they are sitting in Column C to M in my example):

[image: example]

As shown above, I have added two helper rows on top of each schedule. The first helper row is used to find out if there is 2 or more vacancies in each month, if so returns `TRUE`. I have given the name **check.2019.class.1** and **check.2021.class.5** for each of them.

The second helper row is simply showing the range name of each month such as `jan_2019_class.1`, `feb_2019_class.2` etc. I have given the name **NameRng.2019.class.1** and **NameRng.2021.class.5** for each of them.

On the `TEST` sheet I have the following set up:

[image: TEST]

where the look up value in cell `C3` is actually returned by a formula so it can be "dynamically" changed by the user. Please note in the following formula I used a name **ClassNo** which is essentially the value from cell `B3`.

```
=B2&"_"&B1&"_class."&ClassNo
```

I have also named cell `C3` as **Start_MthYrClass** which will be used in my following formula.

The formula for looking up the first available month in **2019** if the start month is `jan_2019_class.1` is:

```
=INDEX(NameRng.2019.class.1,MATCH(1,(TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$11))>=MATCH(Start_MthYrClass,NameRng.2019.class.1,0))*Check.2019.class.1,0))
```

Please note it is an **array formula** so you **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise they will not function correctly.

[image: demo1]

> The logic is to first "filter" the range **NameRng.2019.class.1** using this formula `=TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$11))>=MATCH(Start_MthYrClass,NameRng.2019.class.1,0)`, in which `ROW($1:$11)` represents `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11}` and **TRANSPOSE** will turn it into `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}`. This range of numbers represents the column index in that specific range which is Column C to M (in your case it would be `ROW($1:$56)` as your data is in Column C to BF). Then I use **MATCH** to return the start column index of the look up month `jan_2019_class.1`, and it should return `1` as this month starts in the 1st place/column in the range **NameRng.2019.class.1**. So this is what I am actually comparing: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}>=1`, and it will return `{TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE}`.
>
> Then I multiply the above result with range **Check.2019.class.1** which is essentially `{FALSE,0,FALSE,0,TRUE,0,FALSE,0,TRUE,0,TRUE}`. Then I will get `{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1}`. FYI in Excel `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`, so `TRUE x FALSE = 0` while `TRUE x TRUE = 1`.
>
> Lastly, I use **MATCH** to find out the position of the first `1` in the above result which is the 5th place/column, and then use **INDEX** to return the corresponding value from range **NameRng.2019.class.1** which is `mar_2019_class.1`.

Here is a more universal formula which allows you enter it in the first cell `C6` and drag it down to apply across board, **if you have given names to the relevant cells and ranges in the same way as what I have demonstrated**.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("NameRng."&B6&".class."&ClassNo),MATCH(1,(TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$11))>=MATCH(Start_MthYrClass,INDIRECT("NameRng."&B6&".class."&ClassNo),0))*INDIRECT("Check."&B6&".class."&ClassNo),0)),"")
```

It is also an **array formula** so you **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar.

> It is essentially the same formula as the first one but I have added **IFERROR** to return a blank cell if there is no match, and I used **INDIRECT** to refer to the named ranges dynamically based on the year and class number chosen.

Now, if I change the look up criteria to `mar_2021_class.5`, here is an updated result:

[image: demo2]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Terry W, could you please clarify the rows you "TRANSPOSE" in your universal formula? Thanks!